# Sublime2: How to cross copy text, while keeping the same spacing

Tags: sublimetext2

I have the following two texts

#### text1

```
a
b
c
d
```

#### text2

```
4
6
1
9
```

I'm trying to copy the lines from text 2 to text 1 so that it stays as:

```
a4
b6
c1
d9
```

the replace and the alt f3 command don't help because they are two different texts.

Comment: Write a script that does it (if you're using python, looked `zip()`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow this steps:

- Select `text2` and copy it (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>).
- Select `text1` and get a cursor for every line (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>).
- Move all the cursors to the end of their lines (<kbd>End</kbd>) and paste (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>).

### Example

[image: sublime concat lines]

Comment: just wondering - what utility do you use to make the animations?

Comment: @MattDMo I use byzanz, I discovered it today because I wanted to do that gif. Check [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/107726/how-to-create-animated-gif-images-of-a-screencast)

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `Ctrl+shift+L` to get cursors on each line.